# CVE Security Issues JBoss7

Tags: security, jboss7.x

im looking for a way to solve the following security issues for JBoss7:

1. CVE-2013-6440
2. CVE-2013-4517
3. CVE-2014-0018
4. CVE-2015-5178
5. CVE-2015-5188
6. CVE-2015-5220

When i'm trying to download those packages i always get the same error:

"You do not have access to the requested software." --Redhat Downloadpage

Does anybody know where i can find those packages/fixes?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What JBoss version are you using? It doesn't appear that any of these CVEs affect JBoss versions >= 7, and you've tagged your post with JBoss7.x.

Comment: Keeping a redhat system up to date sounds impossible.  This just goes to show you that `yum update` hasn't worked for 4 years.  Shellshock and heartbleed aren't even that old.

Comment: Hi, its definitely JBoss7 since its the only service installed on the server. The Issues were sent from one of the security scanning tools. Is it possible that these issues are adressed to an older version of jboss? This would make sense because theres an old jboss5 instance installed as well. But it is not up and running.